# How to keep original data structure after processing with Stream API?

Tags: java, java-stream

```
public class Manage {
    
    Map<String, Vehicle> vehicles;

    public static class Vehicle {
        
         String name;
         String model;
         Map<String, Service> services;
         
         public static class Service {
            String id;
            String report;
         }
     } 
}
```

I have these objects where I want to filter out by `services` key. However, I would like to keep the original data structure. Let say, I want to keep the services where the key is `s-1` and keep the structure as the input.

Here is what I have tried. However, the final output of structure is different than the input as it removes `name` and `model`

```
` vehicles.entrySet()
         .stream()
         .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().getServices().containsKey("s-1"))
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
             entry -> entry.getValue()
                 .getServices()
                 .entrySet()
                 .stream()
                 .filter(subEntry -> subEntry.getKey().equals("s-1"))
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue))));`
```

**Update**
Basically, I want to keep everything(all fields & data) except in `services` map, I don't want to keep the records where the key is Not equal to `s-1`

Comment: I do not understand the question. When working with `Stream`s, the source is (normally) unmodified. Please [edit] the post and clarify the question.

Comment: If I'm understanding, you want to store the intermediate result? Just collect without doing the map operation, bind that to a variable, and then do your further processing starting from that.

Comment: `vehicles.forEach(v -> v.services.keySet().removeIf(k -> !k.equals("s-1")));`

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to filter a `services` Map and then create a new instance of `Vehicle` based on newly created Map and initial `name`, `model` properties.

***Note:** it would be cleaner to extract the logic for generating a new map of services into a separate method instead of creating a stream inside the collector.*

```
Map<String, Manage.Vehicle> vehicles = // initializing the map
        
Map<String, Manage.Vehicle> vehiclesFiltered = vehicles.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().getServices().containsKey("s-1"))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        entry -> {
            Map<String, Manage.Vehicle.Service> filteredServices =
                entry.getValue().getServices()
                    .entrySet().stream()
                    .filter(subEntry -> subEntry.getKey().equals("s-1"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        Map.Entry::getKey,
                        Map.Entry::getValue
                    ));
            return new Manage.Vehicle(
                entry.getValue().getName(),
                entry.getValue().getModel(),
                filteredServices
            );
        }
    ));
```

Comment: I do not have constructor for inner static class `Vehicle`

Comment: @Minimum Then use your usual way to create its instances (builder, static method whatever), or introduce a new static factory method (all-args constructor). I don't see any problem with it. The thing is that you need a new instance, otherwise it defeats the whole idea of using streams (you can modify existing objects without streams). Does it make sense to you?